# Django allauth creating dupilcate user?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a customerUser inherited from AbstractUser,if the user Signup with the email aaaa@gmail.com ,
Then the second times, he tries to signup with Google Signin and same Email (aaa@gmail.com)

Does Django-Alluth create a duplicate user, if so how I can avoid this,

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            "username",
            "email",
            "age",
        )  # ne
        email = {"required": True}


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            "username",
            "email",
            "age",
        )  # ne
        email = {"required": True}


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the email field unique to avoid this

```
email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
```

Comment: Really appreciate it, but does this check the Django Alluth authentication process because it's to completely different  ?

Comment: according to the document you can set ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True in settings. more information here https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks i tried the change the model Emailfield to Unique =true and also change for Allauth setting now i am getting this error : NIQUE constraint failed: accounts_customuser.email

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515591/integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-users-customuser-email

Comment: Tried that one didnt work, sadly, I tried both , When i use Django Allauth with the same , it create duplicate user with different username but same email

Comment: ok then , just override save method and check if user exist or not   `User.objects.filter(email__exact=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists()`